# Change Multiple Columns dtypes with multiple different dtypes using loop in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a two list one list contain default dtypes of the column in dataframe and second list contain changing dtypes list how to use which apporach to handel this problem .suppose
Columns Name is ['NameID','Age','Address','DOB']

```
default_dty=['int64',int64,'object','object']
```

When we check my default dtype is

```
NameId  int64
Age     int64
Address object
DOB     object

required_dty=['object',object','object','date']
```

What output I required

```
NameId  object
Age     object
Address object
DOB     date
```

I want changes using loop because I have 30 columns in my dataframe,so I don't do the manually
my code is :

```
for col,rdt in zip(cname.columns,req_dty):
    # data[colu]=data[colu].astype(rdt)
    if 'date' in rdt:    
        a=redt.index('date')
        data[c[a]]=pd.to_datetime(data[c[a]],unit='ns')
    else:
        data[colu]=data[colu].astype(rdt)
```

But It's not working.
Pls Help.....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list of columns for convert to datetimes and dictionary for convert to another dtypes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NameId':list('abc'),
                   'Age':[20,'33','ND'],
                   'Address':list('erd'),
                   'DOB':[1349720105] * 3})
print (df.dtypes)
NameId     object
Age        object
Address    object
DOB         int64
dtype: object
```

---

```
required_dty=['object','int','object','date']

for col,rdt in zip(df.columns,required_dty):
    if 'date' in rdt:    
        df[col]=pd.to_datetime(df[col],unit='ns')
        
    elif 'int'  in rdt:   
        try:
            df[col]=df[col].astype(rdt)
        except ValueError:
            df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(rdt)
    elif 'float'  in rdt:   
        try:
            df[col]=df[col].astype(rdt)
        except ValueError:
            df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
    else:
        df[col]=df[col].astype(rdt)
```

---

```
print(df.dtypes)
NameId             object
Age                 int32
Address            object
DOB        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I get this ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ND'

Comment: I want to required validation facility this type of error so how to do ?

Comment: I'm changing the NaN value with the help of fillna(0) but I don't replace 'nd' string.

Comment: Yes  !! @jezralel

Comment: data[col]=pd.to_numeric(data[col], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)     Why we are not using astype(rdt) in this or because rdt came from the list of this type of column

Comment: @Jai - Because there are values `RD` in numeric, so first is necessary replace them to misisng values by `pd.to_numeric(data[col], errors='coerce')`, then missing values to `0` by `fillna(0)` and then is possible use `.astype(rdt)`, sorry, better here is `rdt`

Comment: No NO Its working great work .....Thank You So Much @jezrael

Comment: @Jai - It seems you accept another answer by accident (green tick), please add green tick to this answer, because only one answer should be choose for correct, not both.

Comment: Ok @jezrael  You Know what's my next Move...... I have selected DataFrame load into the MSSQL SERVER ,But can u suggest pyodbc is compulsory  because I'm using sqlalchemy .

Comment: @Jai - Unfortunately this problematic - saved data to some DB is not easy for me, so please create new question.

Comment: Don't worry about that @jezrael I have load data in postgres,mongodb and mongo to postgres or postgres to mongo. I'm just try to do this this with ms sql server.

Comment: hi ! @jezrael  I'm sending a mail pls check and review and give me a answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do without an explicit loop:

```
# get column names expects date column
no_date_cols = df.columns.difference(['date'])

# set those cols as object type
df[no_date_cols] = df[no_date_cols].astype(object)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='ns')
```